# how to convert a float/integer into a date with strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the following columns:

```
col1 col2
20040929 NaN
NaN 20040925
```

that is both both col1 and col2 are float64 (or int64) numbers.
I am trying to convert these using datetime.strptime() but I get the error

> "cannot convert the series to type 'float'"

and if I convert them to float, I get something like 20040929.0 which strptime does not understand.

How can I transform these columns into date then?
Many thanks

Comment: You will need to use `str()` to convert the `float` to a `string` before passing it to `datetime.strptime()`

Comment: yes I tried but when I convert them to str it converts the date to "20040929.0"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the df to `str` using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype) and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with format string:

```
In [190]:
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d'))

Out[190]:
        col1       col2
0 2004-09-29        NaT
1        NaT 2004-09-25
```

**EDIT**

using `strptime` will be slower and less friendly, firstly converting to `str` introduces `.0` as the dtype is float, we have to split on this, additionally `strptime` doesn't understand `Series` so we have to call `applymap`. On top of this `NaN` will cause `strptime` to bork so we have to do the following:

```
In [203]:
def func(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x.split('.')[0], '%Y%m%d')
    except:
        return pd.NaT
df.astype(str).applymap(func)

Out[203]:
        col1       col2
0 2004-09-29        NaT
1        NaT 2004-09-25
```

**Timings**

If we compare the 2 methods on a 2K row df:

```
In [212]:
%timeit df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d'))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.11 ms per loop

In [213]:    
%%timeit 
def func(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x.split('.')[0], '%Y%m%d')
    except:
        return pd.NaT
df.astype(str).applymap(func)

10 loops, best of 3: 86.3 ms per loop
```

We observe that the `pandas` method is over 10X faster, it's likely that it scales much better as it's vectorised

Comment: yes but it will be slower as you'd have to operate on each element, here we use `to_datetime` on each column which is a vectorised method, all values in the column are converted rather than an element at a time

Comment: Additionally when we cast floats (they're floats because of the presence of `NaN`) you introduce `.0` to the values which would need to be converted to int either as a pre/post processing step

Comment: also `strptime` can't handle `NaN` either as float or str form so it borks on this

Comment: Just one clarification when you apply `to_datetime` the string `NaN` is converted to pandas `NaN` right?

Comment: @The6thSense It's technically `NaT` which is a special `NaN` value for datetimes to indicate invalid values

Comment: So basically `to_datetime` does two things converting to date and converting to NaT.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification beautiful answer.

Comment: @The6thSense yes that is correct this is why I demonstrated both methods to show why the pandas way is better

Comment: update: I actually get an error ValueError: ("time data '' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)", u'occurred at index cancel_dt'). Is this a problem with the missing values? should I transform them before applying to_dateframe?

Comment: actually using to_datetime with the option errors='ignore' shows that some dates in the data appears as 20080420.0 ... what should I do then?

Comment: What version pandas are you using, my code should be able to handle that

Comment: can you try: `df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.split('.')[0], format='%Y%m%d'))`